# JSON in discord.py

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a leveling system but the info instead of editing the XP; it just makes a new dictionary for the user. Here's my code.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

Client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)


os.chdir(r'C:\\Users\\colel\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Sandbox\\Python\\Donut')

@Client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    
    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1
        print(users)

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await Client.send_message(channel, '{} has leveled up to {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end


@Client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready to test")
    await Client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="testing testing"))

Client.run("token")
```

The place where I'm having problems is in update data it just doesn't work it skips the if statement and adds the values.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Here's my code, fix it"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe replace user.id with user